# Is this the right way to compute cosine similarity in PyTroch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

```
cos = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=-1, eps=1e-6)
c = torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 4])
b = torch.FloatTensor([1, 2, 3])
simi = cos(b,c)
tensor(0.9915)
```

I am using dim=-1 in this funciton, does that mean it is a one dimension float list? Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with most indexing in python, -1 refers to last dimension (-2 would be second-to-last, etc...). Using `dim=-1` when initializing cosine similarity means that cosine similarity will be computed along the last dimension of the inputs.

For example, if `b` and `c` were 3-dimensional tensors with size `[X,Y,Z]`, then the result would be a 2-dimensional tensor of size `[X,Y]`. In your case, since the input tensors only have one dimension (size `[3]`), you end up getting a result tensor of size `[]`, i.e. a scalar.

Comment: Hi, jodag, does that mean my method of computing it is not right due to tensor of size[]? How to correct it?

Comment: It's correct if you want a scalar. It's not correct if you don't want a scalar. Since you haven't really provided any context I can't tell you if its semantically correct in your case. What your function does is to take the vector c and vector b and compute the cosine similarity between them. This is a single number, hence why you should expect a scalar in your case. If this is what you expect then you are doing it correctly.

Comment: You can imagine I have two lists of floats, and want to compute similarities between each element from l1 and l2. My code represents one single instance of calculation, so it probably should be scalar.

Comment: Yeah, if this functions is called on a single pair of vectors then a scalar is what you should expect.